# How do I make a trigger with an increment for the values in a column?

Tags: plsql

I have two tables TRIP and DRIVER. When a new set of values in inserted into TRIP (to indicate a new trip being made), the values in the column TOTALTRIPMADE (which is currently empty) in the table DRIVER will increase by one. The trigger should recognise which row to update with the select statement I've made.

This is the trigger I've made:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updatetotaltripmade
AFTER INSERT ON trip
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE

BEGIN
    UPDATE DRIVER 
    SET TOTALTRIPMADE := OLD.TOTALTRIPMADE+1
    WHERE (SELECT L#
        FROM TRIP
        INNER JOIN DRIVER
        ON TRIP.L# = DRIVER.L#;)

END;
/
```

However I get this error: 
`ORA-04098: trigger 'CSCI235.UPDATETOTALTRIPMADE' is invalid and failed re-validation`

What should I edit in my code so that my trigger works? Thanks!

Comment: did you try show SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER trigger_name; The trigger didn't get compiled successfully it seems and is invalid in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has syntax error due to which the trigger is not compiling,I have modified the trigger and it should get compiled successfully with desired results.Please check and feedback.

Please find below the script to create table and compile the trigger,

```
drop table trip;
create table trip (trip_id number(10),L# varchar2(10));
drop table driver;
create table driver(driver_id number(10),TOTALTRIPMADE number(10),L# varchar2(10));

drop trigger updatetotaltripmade;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updatetotaltripmade
AFTER INSERT ON trip
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE 
DECLARE 

BEGIN

UPDATE DRIVER 
SET TOTALTRIPMADE = nvl(TOTALTRIPMADE,0) + 1
WHERE DRIVER.L# = :new.L#;

END;
/

select * from ALL_OBJECTS where object_type ='TRIGGER';
```

Output is below from the tests i did on https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/
There are no issues in the code.The trigger is compiled successfully and is valid.

[image: oraclelivesqllink]

Comment: @Yena -Please mark and upvote relevant answer,that helps all visitors of stack overflow.

Comment: oh right, sorry! im still new to stackoverflow. but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One error you made is in trying to reference `OLD.TOTALTRIPMADE` in your `SET` clause since no alias `OLD` exists, and unless the table `TRIP` contains a `TOTALTRIPMADE` column then the `:OLD` record won't contain a `TOTALTRIPMADE` column either (note that since this is an insert trigger the `:OLD` record either won't exist or won't contain any meaningful data anyway).  Another error is in your `WHERE` clause where you are selecting `L#` from `TRIP` joined to `DRIVER`, but you aren't linking it back to the `DRIVER` table that you are attempting to update.  Instead just update `DRIVER` where `L#` is equal the `:NEW` value of `L#` from the trip table. The final error I noticed is your use of , the `:=` assignment operator which is for PLSQL code, however you are using it within SQL so just use `=` without the colon:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updatetotaltripmade
AFTER INSERT ON trip
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE

BEGIN
    UPDATE DRIVER 
    SET TOTALTRIPMADE = nvl(TOTALTRIPMADE,0)+1
    WHERE L# = :NEW.L#;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply! unfortunately i still get the same error.
the trigger should only work when both values of L# in TRIP and DRIVER are the same, afterwards the value of totaltripmade for that particular value of L# will increase by one. thats why i tried to use inner join

Comment: The `WHERE` clause in the update statement ensures that `L#` in both `TRIP` and `DRIVER` are the same. `:NEW.L#` comes from `TRIP` while the bare `L#` comes from `DRIVER`

Comment: the same error when i try to create the trigger! when i try to insert a value into trip to ensure that the trigger works, i get ORA-04098: trigger 'User.UPDATETOTALTRIPMADE' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: What errors does `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER updatetotaltripmade; ` show?

Comment: LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/2  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/13  PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."L#": invalid identifier
SQL>

Comment: Okay, the problem is with the hash symbol `#`. Oracle doesn't like it as part of an unquoted identifier.  to fix that, either remove the # from your column names, or quote the `L#` column with double quotes like this `"L#"` whenever you reference it.  I've updated my code above to quote the identifier, and added the `nvl` function to the right side of the set statement just in case totaltripmade is null.

Comment: ah.. im still getting the same errors. ill just describe the tables to you so maybe it might be easier to debug.
The table TRIP consists of T#(trip number), L#(license number), REG#(registration number) and TRIP_DATE
The table DRIVER consists of E#(employee number), L#(license number), Status, and the empty column TOTALTRIPMADE

Comment: This limited example shows it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a002b8/2, try ensuring that all columns with hash symbols in their names are properly quoted.

Comment: @Sentinel - Where did you read  "Oracle doesn't like it as part of an unquoted identifier". If you read oracle  documentation underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#) are allowed identifiers. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Comment: Just noticed in your error statment it looks like you missed the colon `:` in front of the word `NEW` it's required to make it work. it needs to be `:NEW`

Comment: Looks at  the answer with demonstration and screenshot, seems like you are doing something seriously wrong or else there is no way the trigger would compile with error? Could you blindly copy/paste the code and compile the trigger and feedback.

Comment: @VN'sCorner I didn't but I was having issues over at SQL Fiddle when buiding my example fiddle when I didn't quote them.  could have been other issues, as it's now working without the quoted identifiers in this updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bc45f/1

Comment: Ok, no worries. I agree that its never a good practice to have a column with #, however i have seen a lot of them in metadata tables.Use https://livesql.oracle.com instead of sqlfiddle for Oracle database, you get a schema and has ability to create objects as desired.

Comment: @VN'sCorner Thanks for the tip I'll add livesql to my list of known scratch pads and take a look at if for the future.